# Javascript links with Python not working (using Ajax and Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I've been trying to make a website that gets information from another website (top 10 best tetris players) and then log it into my console. I'm experimenting with pandas for Python and Javascript with ajax.

The original Python code worked in nodejs, but I need it to work on a website, so I tried to adapt by using ajax.

Now I'm getting this [error code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWnZ2.png) and sometimes this [error code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty79a.png). I'm not sure when which one happens. Always code 404 though.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

HTML/Javascript code:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>website test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  
</head>

<body>
    <button>click me for nothing to happen</button>
    <script>
        function ajaxCall() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/makeTop10",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("call happened.") //extra test
                }
            });
        }
        ajaxCall();

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/makeTop10")
def makeTop10():
    list = pd.read_html("https://listfist.com/list-of-tetris-high-scores-nes-pal")

    data = list[0]
    output = ""
    for i in range(10):
        output += "{: <10}{: <20}{: <25}\n".format(
            data.at[i, "Rank"],
            data.at[i, "Player Name"],
            data.at[i, "Score(2 April, 2022)[source]"],
        )

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your code to this and it's working

HTML/Javascript code:

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title>website test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  
</head>

<body>
    <button>click me for nothing to happen</button>
    <script>
        function ajaxCall() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/makeTop10",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("call happened.") //extra test
                }
            });
        }
        ajaxCall();

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Python code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
from flask_cors import CORS # added

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # added

@app.route("/makeTop10")
def makeTop10():
    list = pd.read_html("https://listfist.com/list-of-tetris-high-scores-nes-pal")

    data = list[0]
    output = ""
    for i in range(10):
        output += "{: <10}{: <20}{: <25}\n".format(
            data.at[i, "Rank"],
            data.at[i, "Player Name"],
            data.at[i, "Score(2 April, 2022)[source]"],
        )

    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for this reply! However, when I copypasted your code (and changed the 5000 to 5500 because my localhost is that for some reason) It still gives me this same error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) makeTop10:1 (makeTop10:1 is the url used in the ajax call)   I'm using the live server extension for visual studio code, could this be the problem?

Comment: Just close the VSCode and run the script using a terminal and see what happens

Comment: That doesn't work either :C